# Neural Network Always Predicting Average Value

Tags: neural-network, mlp, jax

I'm trying to train a neural network to **approximate a known scalar function of two variables**; however, no matter the parameters of my training, the network always just ends up simply **predicting the average value** of the true outputs.

I am using an MLP and have tried:

- using **several network depths and widths**
- different **optimizers** (SGD and ADAM)
- different **activations** (ReLU and Sigmoid)
- changing the **learning rate** (several points within the range 0.1 to 0.001)
- **increasing the data** (to 10,000 points)
- increasing the **number of epochs** (to 2,000)
- and **different random seeds**
  to no avail.

My loss function is **MSE** and always plateaus to a value of about 5.14.

Regardless of changes I make, I get the following results:
[image]

Where the **blue surface is the function to be approximated**, and the g**reen surface is the MLP approximation** of the function, having a value that is roughly the average of the true function over that domain (the true average is **2.15** with a square of **4.64** - not far from the loss plateau value).

I feel like I could be missing something very obvious and have just been looking at it for too long. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

I've attached my code here (I'm using JAX):

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import grad, jit, vmap, random, value_and_grad
import flax
import flax.linen as nn
import optax


seed = 2
key, data_key = random.split(random.PRNGKey(seed))
x1, x2, y= generate_data(data_key)  # Data generation function

# Using Flax - define an MLP
class MLP(nn.Module):
  features: Sequence[int]

  @nn.compact
  def __call__(self, x):
    for feat in self.features[:-1]:
      x = nn.relu(nn.Dense(feat)(x))
    x = nn.Dense(self.features[-1])(x)
    return x

# Define function that returns JITted loss function
def make_mlp_loss(input_data, true_y):

  def mlp_loss(params):
    pred_y = model.apply(params, input_data)
    loss_vector = jnp.square(true_y.reshape(-1) - pred_y)
    return jnp.average(loss_vector)

  # Outer scope incapsulation saves the data and true output
  return jit(mlp_loss)


# Concatenate independent variable vectors to be proper input shape
input_data = jnp.hstack((x1.reshape(-1, 1), x2.reshape(-1, 1)))

# Create loss function with data and true output
mlp_loss = make_mlp_loss(input_data, y)

# Create function that returns loss and gradient
loss_and_grad = value_and_grad(mlp_loss)

# Example architectures I've tried
architectures = [[16, 16, 1], [8, 16, 1], [16, 8, 1], [8, 16, 8, 1], [32, 32, 1]]

# Only using one seed but iterated over several
for seed in [645]:
  for architecture in architectures:
    # Create model
    model = MLP(architecture)
    
    # Initialize model with random parameters
    key, params_key = random.split(key)
    dummy = jnp.ones((1000, 2))
    params = model.init(params_key, dummy)

    # Create optimizer
    opt = optax.adam(learning_rate=0.01) #sgd
    opt_state = opt.init(params)

    
    epochs = 50
    for i in range(epochs):
      # Get loss and gradient 
      curr_loss, curr_grad = loss_and_grad(params)
      if i % 5 == 0:
        print(curr_loss)

      # Update
      updates, opt_state = opt.update(curr_grad, opt_state)
      params = optax.apply_updates(params, updates)
      
    print(f"Architecture: {architecture}\nLoss: {curr_loss}\nSeed: {seed}\n\n")
```

Comment: what is the shape of pred_y in mlp_loss? it looks a bit suspicious that you flatten true_y but not predictions

Comment: @lejlot you're an absolute saint. Just flattening `true_y` was necessary for an earlier version of my code, but I needed to flatten both after some changes. Now training is working as expected, thank you so much.

Comment: Sure thing, yet another issue with automated broadcasting :) this feature is really the source of all evil in python libraries ;)

Comment: FYI JAX provides a flag, `jax_numpy_rank_promotion`, that you can use to warn or error on this implicit rank promotion behavior if you wish: https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/rank_promotion_warning.html